# Find duplicate Values in a SQL Table and add unique value in a column

Tags: mysql, sql, count, subquery, window-functions

I have a table with  locations and there are duplicates because there are locations with same name that belongs to different counties.

```
  +------+-----------+-----------
| ID   | location   | parent_id  | 
+------+-----------+------------+
|  1   | Country   |    0       |         
|  2   | County 1  |    1       |         
|  3   | County 2  |    1       |         
|  4   | A         |    2       |         
|  5   | B         |    2       |         
|  6   | C         |    2       |          
|  7   | A         |    3       |         
|  8   | E         |    3       |           
|  9   | B         |    3       |         
+---- -+-----------+------------+
```

I would like to create and insert in column duplicate for each duplicate ID value . The result should look like this: ( Would be better to add ID in duplicate column to all duplicates excepting  the one with smallest ID)

```
| ID   | location     | parent_id  | duplicate|
+------+-----------+------------+----------+
|  1   | Country   |    0       |         |
|  2   | County 1  |    1       |         | 
|  3   | County 2  |    1       |         |  
|  4   | A         |    2       |     4   | 
|  5   | B         |    2       |     5   | 
|  6   | C         |    2       |         | 
|  7   | A         |    3       |     7   | 
|  8   | E         |    3       |         |    
|  9   | B         |    3       |     9   | 
+---- -+-----------+------------+---------+
```

I use this to list the rows:

```
SELECT a.* FROM mytable a

JOIN (SELECT location, COUNT(*)
FROM mytable 
GROUP BY location
HAVING count(*) > 1 ) b
ON a.location= b.location
ORDER BY a.location
```

Comment: I do not see duplicates. `A` with `ID`=`4` has `parent_id`=`2`, `A` with `ID`=`7` has `parent_id`=`3`. Both `A`'s are unique. Which in the tree structure looks like: `Country->Country1->A` and respectivelly: `Country->Country2->A`

Comment: What is a *location* in your data structure?

Comment: I have made the changes to the questions. It is about duplicate "location" value not the ID

Comment: The "Location" is unique too. See my previous comment. The first `A` is in `Country1` and the second `A` is in `Country2`. Let's say a `New York` city can exists in `USA` and `Canada` and even in `Poland`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a window count can do what you want:

```
select t.*,
    case when count(*) over(partition by location) > 1 then id end duplicate
from mytable t
```

This requires MySQL 8.0. In earlier versions, an alternative is a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*,
    case when (select count(*) from mytable t1 where t1.location = t.location) > 1 then id end duplicate
from mytable t
```

Comment: As to me, the question is not clear. So, even if your queries are correct, i can't up-vote your answer. This statement: *there are duplicates because there are locations with same name that belongs to different counties* is complete misundersanding. Please, see my comments to the question.

Comment: Ok. I will not call them duplicates. I will call them locations with same value. So, no matter that each one has different id you have to admit that you can find twice location A and location B in column Location.  So, i want just to add in column duplicate the id of each location that is found more then once in column location